# Sending a Rack request through rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send a request through `./bin/rails c`, but for some reason rails keep blocking my request.

I tried the following:

```
./bin/rails c

req = Rack::MockRequest.env_for('http://localhost:3000/courses') # courses is defined and accessible by the browser
Rails.application.call(req)
> ... <h1>Blocked host: localhost</h1>\n</header>\n<div id=\"container\">\n  
> <h2>To allow requests to localhost, add the following to your environment configuration:</h2>\n  
> <pre>config.hosts &lt;&lt; \"localhost\"</pre>\n</div>\n\n\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

If I run `Rails.application.config.hosts` I have the following hosts

```
Rails.application.config.hosts
=> [".localhost", #<IPAddr: IPv4:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0>, #<IPAddr: IPv6:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000>]
```

Even when I add 'localhost', 'localhost:3000', etc... Rails won't receive my request. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you really want to send a request through the console? Thats something that you would use integration tests or cURL for.

Comment: I'm just learning rails internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `HTTP_HOST` header to one of the allowed hosts. While you would assume that `Rack::MockRequest` would set this to localhost its actually nil and `ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization` rightly rejects the request.

```
irb(main):001:0> req = Rack::MockRequest.env_for('http://localhost:3000/courses')
irb(main):002:0> req['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost'
irb(main):003:0> Rails.application.call(req)
Started GET "/courses" for  at 2020-12-27 01:00:36 +0100
   (0.4ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by CoursesController#index as HTML
Hello World!
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 161)


=> [200, {"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "X-Download-Options"=>"noopen", "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies"=>"none", "Referrer-Policy"=>"strict-origin-when-cross-origin", "Content-Type"=>"text/plain; charset=utf-8", "ETag"=>"W/\"a591a6d40bf420404a011733cfb7b190\"", "Cache-Control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", "X-Request-Id"=>"044b7694-bc4c-43ee-b97e-416d510bbdc5", "X-Runtime"=>"0.200952"}, #<Rack::BodyProxy:0x0000000004806228 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x00000000048062a0 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x00000000048064d0 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x0000000004806570 @body=#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x0000000004806840 @body=["Hello World"], @block=#<Proc:0x00000000048067f0 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:32>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x0000000004806520 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:15>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x00000000048064a8 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x0000000004806250 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:30>, @closed=false>, @block=#<Proc:0x00000000048061d8 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:15>, @closed=false>]
irb(main):004:0>
```

Another way of doing this is by using the instance of `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session` which is available through `app` in the console:

```
# method, path, options
app.process(:GET, '/courses', headers: { host: 'localhost' })
```